# Maximize minimum distance between arrays

Tags: algorithm, optimization, dynamic-programming, combinatorics, backtracking

Lets say that you are given n sorted arrays of numbers and you need to pick **one** number from each array such that the minimum distance between the n chosen elements is maximized.

Example:

```
arrays:
[0, 500]
[100, 350]
[200]
```

`2<=n<=10` and every array could have `~10^3-10^4` elements.

In this example the optimal solution to maximize minimum distance is pick numbers: 500, 350, 200 or 0, 200, 350 where min distance is 150 and is the maximum possible of every combination.

I am looking for an algorithm to solve this. I know that I could binary search the max min distance but I can't see how to decide is there is a solution with max min distance of at least d, in order for the binary search to work. I am thinking maybe dynamic programming could help but haven't managed to find a solution with dp.

Of course generating all combination with n elements is not efficient. I have already tried backtracking but it is slow since it tries every combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to give an algorithm that for a given distance `d`, will output whether it is possible to make a selection where the distance between any pair of chosen numbers is at least `d`. Then, you can binary-search the maximum `d` for which the algorithm outputs "YES", in order to find the answer to your problem.

Assume the minimum distance `d` be given. Here is the algorithm:

```
for every permutation p of size n do:
    last := -infinity
    ok := true
    
    for p_i in p do:
        x := take the smallest element greater than or equal to last+d in the p_i^th array (can be done efficiently with binary search).
        if no such x was found; then
            ok = false
            break
        end

        last = x
    done

    if ok; then
        return "YES"
    end
done

return "NO"
```

So, we brute-force the order of arrays. Then, for every possible order, we use a greedy method to choose elements from each array, following the order. For example, take the example you gave:

```
arrays:
[0, 500]
[100, 350]
[200]
```

and assume `d = 150`. For the permutation `1 3 2`, we first take 0 from the 1st array, then we find the smallest element in the 3rd array that is greater than or equal to 0+150 (it is 200), then we find the smallest element in the 2nd array which is greater than or equal to 200+150 (it is 350). Since we could find an element from every array, the algorithm outputs "YES".  But for `d = 200` for instance, the algorithm would output "NO" because none of the possible orderings would result in a successful selection.

The complexity for the above algorithm is `O(n! * n * log(m))` where `m` is the maximum number of elements in an array. I believe it would be sufficient, since `n` is very small. (For `m = 10^4`, `10! * 10 * 13 ~ 5*10^8`. It can be computed under a second on a modern CPU.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer !!
It was exactly what I was seeking for, a simple and clear algorithm with a simple example and explanation!!!
I was thinking for a couple of days about your algorithm correctness. I am not sure why it guarantees to find best answer??
(I did not find any counterexample and to a great degree your approach makes sense, I am just thinking how to prove the correctness - in simple terms/thoughts, not a mathematical proof)

Comment: @frank
Inside the 1st for-loop, we have a fixed `d` and a fixed order of arrays. First, we consider the first array in the perm. The number we choose from this array is going to be the smallest number, so it doesn't make sense to choose a number which is not the minimum in this array. So, we take the minimum element. Now moving on to 2nd array.. The same thing applies. It doesn't make sense to take an element when there is a smaller one that is greater than the last+d. Moving on 3rd.. etc. 
I hope it's clearer now.

Answer (score 2):

n ≤ 10 suggests that we can take an exponential dependence on n. Here's
an O(2<sup>n</sup> m n)-time algorithm where m is the total size of the
arrays.

The dynamic programming approach I have in mind is, for each subset of
arrays, calculate all of the pairs (maximum number, minimum distance) on
the efficient frontier, where we have to choose one number from each of
the arrays in the subset. By efficient frontier I mean that if we have
two pairs (a, b) ≠ (c, d) with a ≤ c and b ≥ d, then (c, d) is not on
the efficient frontier. We'll want to keep these frontiers sorted for
fast merges.

The base case with the empty subset is easy: there's one pair, (minimum
distance = ∞, maximum number = −∞).

For every nonempty subset of arrays in some order that extends the
inclusion order, we compute a frontier for each array in the subset,
representing the subset of solutions where that array contributes the
maximum number. Then we merge these frontiers. (Naively this costs us
another factor of log n, which maybe isn't worth the hassle to avoid
given that n ≤ 10, but we can avoid it by merging the arrays once at the
beginning to enable future merges to use bucketing.)

To construct a new frontier from a subset of arrays and another array
also involves a merge. We initialize an iterator at the start of the
frontier (i.e., least maximum number) and an iterator at the start of
the array (i.e., least number). While neither iterator is past the end,

1. Emit a candidate pair (min(minimum distance, array number − maximum
   number), array number).
2. If the min was less than or equal to minimum distance, increment the
   frontier iterator. If the min was less than or equal to array number
   − maximum number, increment the array iterator.

Cull the candidate pairs to leave only the efficient frontier. There is
an elegant way to do this in code that is more trouble to explain.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!!! 
I think I get the main idea but could you provide an example ??

Comment: So you keep  all candidates and them keep only efficient?? How can you do this operation efficiently?
Also lets say you have 2 arrays A=[2,4], B=[6,10] , in the beginning you have empty subset E={} with frontier: (10^10, -10^10) (lets assume 10^10 is the highest value). Then you create frontier of E union A = [(10^10,2)], E union B = [(10^10,6)], and then A union B is what ?

Comment: @frank We get [(4,6),(8,10)] for {A} followed by B, and nothing for {B} followed by A, so the result is [(4,6),(8,10)].

Comment: How is this since you mentioned initially for empty subset we have: (minimum distance = ∞, maximum number = −∞) thus for A = A union empty we yield [(10^10,2)] following the rules (if infinity = 10^10 in our example) ?? Can you provide a complete minimal example to understand your algorithm??

Comment: Since n is a constant (and small), isn't this technically O(m)?

Comment: @גלעדברקן The array lengths are bounded too so it's technically O(1) even.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat how is it O(1)?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur bounded input size + really big big-O constant.

Answer (score 0):

Lets look at an example with optimal choices, `x` (horizontal arrays A, B, C, D):

```
A            x
B    b    x        b
C   x             c
D     d             x
```

Our recurrence based on range could be: let `f(low, excluded)` represent the maximum closest distance between two chosen elements (from arrays 1 to `n`) of the subset without elements in `excluded`, where `low` is the lowest chosen element. Then:

```
(1)

f(low, excluded) when |excluded| = n-1:
  max(low)
    for low in the only permitted array

(2)

f(low, excluded):
  max(
    min(
      a - low,
      f(a, excluded')
    )
  )
  for a ≥ low, a not in excluded'
    where excluded' = excluded ∪ {low's array}
```

We can limit `a`. For one thing the maximum we can achieve is

```
(3)

m = (highest - low) / (n - |excluded| - 1)
```

which means `a` need not go higher than `low + m`.

Secondly, we can store results for all `f(a, excluded')`, keyed by `excluded'` (we have 2^10 possible keys), each in a decorated binary tree ordered by `a`. The decoration will be the highest result achievable in the right subtree, meaning we can find the max for all `f(v, excluded'), v ≥ a` in logarithmic time.

The latter establishes a dominance relationship and clearly we are intetested in *both* a larger `a` and a larger `f(a, excluded')` so as to maximise the `min` function in (2). Picking an `a` in the middle, we can use a binary search. If we have:

```
a - low < max(v, excluded'), v ≥ a

  where max(v, excluded') is the lookup
  for a in the decorated tree
```

then we look to the right since `max(v, excluded)` indicates there's a better answer on the right, where `a - low` is also larger.

And if we have:

```
a - low ≥ max(v, excluded), v ≥ a
```

then we record this candidate and look to the left since to the right, the answer is fixed at `max(v, excluded)`, given that `a - low` could not decrease.

In order to conduct the binary search on the range, `[low, low + m]` (see (3)), rather than merge and label all the arrays at the outset, we can keep them separate and compare the closest candidates to `mid` out of each array we are currently permitted to choose `a` from. (The trees have the mixed results, keyed by subset.) (The flow of this part is not completely clear to me.)

Worst case with this method, given that `n = C` is constant seems to be

```
O(C * array_length * 2^C * C * log(array_length) * log(C * array_length))

C * array_length is the iteration on low
Each low can be paired with 2^C inclusions
C * log(array_length) is the separated binary-search
And log(C * array_length) is the tree lookup
```

Simplifying:

```
= O(array_length * log^2(array_length))
```

although in practice, there could be many dead-end branches that exit early where a full selection wouldn't be possible.

In case, it wasn't clear, the iteration is on a fixed lowest element in the selection. In other words, we want the best `f(low, excluded)` for all different `low`s (and `excluded`s). For bottom-up, we would iterate from the highest value down so our results for `a` get stored as we iterate.